# Checkbox enabled on screen but code says disabled

Tags: ruby, checkbox, watir

OK i have a weird one
I have a check-box that is visible on the page and is click-able. But when i view source it says:

```
 <input disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" class="billingCheck"  />
```

my code to is follows:

```
 browser.checkbox(:class => 'billingCheck').set
```

I get the following error:

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.4/lib/watir/element.rb:84:in
>   `asse rt_enabled': object {:class=>"billingCheck"} and  is disabled
>   (Watir::Exception: :ObjectDisabledException)

I tried to use the following but it passed right over the code.

```
if
browser.checkbox(:class => 'billingCheck').visible?
browser.checkbox(:class => 'billingCheck').set
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there more than one checkbox with the same class at the page? What does this return? `browser.checkboxes(:class => 'billingCheck').size`

Comment: yes there could be more checkboxes, they get dynamically created when creating a new account. Each checkbox has the same code

Comment: Then your code accesses a checkbox that is disabled.

Comment: Disabled is not the same as not visible. Of course Disabled.disabled seems to be a double negative, so maybe that means enabled? ;-)  You should get the developers to make a better web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
browser.checkboxes(:class => 'billingCheck').each {|checkbox| checkbox.set if checkbox.visible?}
```

Comment: That did set the checkbox, only problem is for some reason when I click on the save button if will remove the check from the checkbox

Comment: Have you checked the functionality of the website manually?  It could be a bug with the site itself if it's one that's in production.

Comment: manually it works fine the checkbox holds its value on submit

Comment: The best thing would be if you could provide the site URL, if it is public, so we could take a look. If not, could you share page HTML? Just make sure the page you provide behaves the same as the one you are testing.